# Creating an action inside a controller, after it has been generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, controller

I am working on a rails app, and have generated a Controller via

```
rails g controller Pics index upload
```

but now I would like to add another action

```
delete
```

do I do this by manually adding a delete method in the Pics controller?

Or do I need to run another generation.  My concern is that by adding manually something may not get included (not sure what it would be, but something under the hood.)

Is this the best way of adding a new action to a generated controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add manually, just make sure you have the right route on your `routes.rb`.
Let's say you create your `delete` action inside your Pics controller.

```
def delete
  # do stuff
end
```

On your `routes.rb`, you need to append the route to your resource like this, remembering to analyse if it is a resource that acts upon a member of your resource, or a collection. (More about this you can read on this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).

```
resource :pics do
  collection do
    post :delete
  end
end
```

Or

```
resource :pics do
  member do
    post :delete
  end
end
```

Remember that all `RESTFUL` actions are handled by default by the rails router, again, try to read the guide i showed earlier for precise information about the topic. Hope it helps.